# Reset DataGrid.SelectedIndex after user has selected another

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

In the UI I'm working with, in a `DataGrid`, there are cases where the user might select a different row, but after a dialog interaction, the old row needs to be shown as being selected once again. If I simply try

```
BundleQueueDG.SelectedIndex = currentBundleIndex;
```

that does not do anything and in fact, once the  `SelectionChanged` method exits, it changes to the new value. What is the best way to "re-select" the previously-selected row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the SelectedItem property. Preserve what was selected before and set the SelectedItem with what was previously selected in your event.
Something like this:

```
private void DgDataGrid_OnSelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int newIndex = (sender as DataGrid).SelectedIndex / 2;
        if (Convert.ToInt32(newIndex) >= 1)
            (sender as DataGrid).SelectedItem = previous;
        else
        {
            previous = (sender as DataGrid).CurrentItem;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but still doesn't work - selection changes even if restoring old value of ``SelectedIndex`` and setting ``e.Handled = true``

Comment: what is e.NewValue? This is the new value that will be set as current row index and is in the event args.

Comment: ``SelectionChangedEventArgs`` does not have a ``NewValue`` property.

Comment: Updated the answer to set SelectedItem with what was selected before.

Comment: It is important to note that you should only use one of SelectedItem, SelectedIndex, and SelectedValue at the same time. Also, you should only use ValueMemberPath when using SelectedValue. Otherwise you might get strange results.

Comment: Well SelectedIndex for the current solution is just a means to set a value for CurrentItem and then set the value for SelectedItem.
Ideally it would be replaced with the Conrad's logic of dialogue box

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding - got pulled off this. I tried the new code; it still does not work, using ``SelectedItem`` and its ``DataRowView`` content. Also, in the above code: why are you testing if ``SelectedIndex`` is -1, 0 or 1? What is the point of that?

Comment: Also FYI I am using the ``SelectionChanged`` event, not the ``SelectedCellsChanged`` event. (Are you saying I need to switch to get this to work?)

Comment: @Conrad the logic is to use the `SelectedCellsChanged` event yes.
Also the logic I am using is just to differentiate between when to update. You should replace it with your logic. With this example I wanted to show a way how it can be done.

Comment: That worked! Would never have guessed I needed to use the ``SelectedCellsChanged`` event. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Another note: I needed to unhook the called method from the ``SelectedCellsChanged`` event before I set the ``SelectedItem`` otherwise the method gets called when I set. I then reconnect after the set.